# Why is my Ubuntu 12.04 not booting after GRUB?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I've seen a lot of similar issues, but none have quite answered my question. To elaborate, I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8. I am using a linux usb creator to boot linux. I have tried LiliUSB creator, pendrive linux usb creator, and unetbootin. All three have given me the same result. When I select my flash drive from the BIOS to boot into, it successfully shows the GRUB menu. The GRUB menu however, is black instead of purple that I've seen when normally booting Ubuntu. It displays the normal options to, try linux, intall linux, and boot repair. However, if i select any of these options they all result in a black screen and nothing happening. I am trying a new flash drive in a moment to see if this fixes it. If it doesn't though I would still appreciate any advice or answers I can get. If this is a solved issue please redirect me! Thank you!

Also this is marked as a repeat question, but the question it was marked the same as was unresolved and all answers that were relevant were graphics driver solutions. Mine was a boot error and was resolved from me digging elsewhere in the askubuntu forum, so technically yes it's repeat, but not to that question, so I hope it gets remarked as a solved answer or re-linked to the appropriate question so others who encounter the same issue which isn't graphics related, might find help in this question.

Extra info on my computer if it helps:
ASUS x55c model 
intel hd 3000 graphics
i3 duo core processor
4gb ddr3
Linux is not installed currently (hence my problem)
Currently running: Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer through some digging around! All I had to do was disable secure boot from the BIOS I hope this helps anyone else!